# sqlalchemy call mysql procedure to read the multiple results

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the multiple results from procedure in mysql by using sqlalchemy in python.

```
async def create_user(db: AsyncSession, user: UserInfo):
    try:
        result_proxy = await db.execute(
            text("CALL create_user(:account)"), 
            {
                "account": user.account
            }
        )
        logging.info("result_proxy: %s", result_proxy)
        # Fetch the first result set
        db_user = result_proxy.fetchone()

        logging.info("db_user: %s", db_user)
        
        # Move to the next result set
        if result_proxy.nextset():
            # Fetch the second result set
            db_user_setting = result_proxy.fetchone()
            logging.info("db_user_setting: %s", db_user_setting)
        else:
            db_user_setting = None

    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        logging.error("Error creating user: %s", e)
        await db.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Database creating user failed.")

    return db_user, db_user_setting
```

mysql procedure code is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `data`.`create_user`(
    IN p_account VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_user_id VARCHAR(255);
 
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        -- Rollback the transaction in case of an error
        ROLLBACK;
    END;

    SET v_user_id = UUID_SHORT();
       
    START TRANSACTION;
    
    INSERT INTO data.user_info (
        account,
        user_id
    )
    VALUES(
        p_account,
        v_user_id
    );

    INSERT INTO data.user_setting (
        user_id,
        created_name
    )
    VALUES(
        v_user_id,
        'Javis'
    );
    
    COMMIT;
   
    -- Select the newly created records to return them as a result set
    SELECT * FROM data.user_info WHERE user_id = v_user_id;
    SELECT * FROM data.user_setting  WHERE user_id = v_user_id;
   
END
```

I don't know why I got `Error creating user: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.` I run the procedure in the mysql script, it can create the row in the tables successfully.
Would you mind giving me some advices?

Best regards

Comment: I would suspect it might be something to do with `async` here. But, you'd get a whole lot more info if you `import traceback` and then use `print(traceback.format_exc())` inside the exception, rather than just `print(e)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `mysql` but I think you need to declare `OUT` variables.

Then seems like you could use a join to return the result from a single query.

Maybe like this:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `data`.`create_user`(
    IN p_account VARCHAR(255),
    OUT user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    OUT account VARCHAR(255),
    OUT created_name VARCHAR(255)
)
...
SELECT data.user_info.user_id, data.user_info.account, data.user_info.user_setting.created_name INTO user_id, account, created_name FROM data.user_info JOIN data.user_setting ON data.user_info.user_id = data.user_setting WHERE data.user_info.user_id = v_user_id;
```